# how to display data to pie chart from database?

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts

I can't display the pie chart using these statement

```
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'service');
            data.addColumn('number', 'score');
        for (i = 0; i<pie1[i]; i++)
            data.addRow([pie1[i][0],parseInt(pie1[i][1]]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };
```

I was able to connect to database with this

```
    $query2 ="SELECT * FROM services";
    $step= $con -> prepare($query2);

    if ($step->execute()) {
        $resultSet= $step->get_result();
        $data= $resultSet->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        print_r($data);


        echo "<script>
        var pie1=".json_encode($data)."
        </script>";

    }else{
        print_r($step->errorinfo());
    }
```

I did exactly what was in the tutorial but it doesn't show any outputs.. please help me

This is my PHP code

```html
<?php session_start();
    include_once 'connection.php';
    $query= "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result= mysqli_query($con, $query);

    //...data for pie chart...
    $query2 ="SELECT * FROM services";
    $step= $con -> prepare($query2);

    if ($step->execute()) {
        $resultSet= $step->get_result();
        $data= $resultSet->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        print_r($data);


        echo "<script>
        var pie1=".json_encode($data)."
        </script>";

    }else{
        print_r($step->errorinfo());
    }

 ?>
```

and this is my script code

```html
    <script>
      google.charts.load("current", {"packages":["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw_my_chart);
      function draw_my_chart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'service');
            data.addColumn('number', 'score');
        for (i = 0; i<pie1.length; i++)
            data.addRow([pie1[i][0],parseInt(pie1[i][1])]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

```html
<body>
<div class="chart-area">
        <canvas id="Services"></canvas>
    <div id="donutchart" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; margin-top: -110px;">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Step through it: have you verified your connection and validated to you can see data through a simple query? Have you validated there is data in the source table?

Comment: yes. with the print_r($data); I was able to display the data stored in my database

Comment: do you see errors in the console?

Comment: An obvious mistake is, I think, the condition `i<pie1[i]` - it should be something like `i < pie1.length`. Still, you need to add more information for a full solution. If your database access works fine, just put the client (js) stuff, but something that is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Professor Abronsius-- no there is no error

Comment: Seeing the complete code might help as the javascript does not call the `.draw()` method nor do you assign the `options` - if there is no error ( which is a slight surprise ) and the above yields a proper recordset then there must be something else going on ( or not ) to which we are not privy

Comment: here i have added my complete code